# IF statement using strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Hi guys im near the end of an assignment and I tend to always get stuck on `if/else` problems in Java. my little snippet here:

```
// a taxi fare program where if pickup or drop off point is the airport
// and\or CBD the surcharge changes accordingly.

if(!pickup.equals("CBD") && !dropOff.equals("CBD")) {
    Surcharge = 15.0;
} else if (!pickup.equals("airport") && !dropOff.equals("CBD")) {
    Surcharge = 15.0;
} else if (!pickup.equals("airport") || !dropOff.equals("airport")) { 
    Surcharge = 10.0;
} else if (!pickup.equals("CBD") || !dropOff.equals("CBD")) {  
    Surcharge = 5.0;
} else {
    Surcharge = 0.0;
}
```

Doesn't error, but doesn't seem to be testing right. For example, if I put in `"airport"` as pickup, but then a random location for `dropOff`, it will still print out a $15 surcharge when it should be $10. But if i put `"CBD"` as `pickup` and airport as drop off, it prints $15 correctly. Sorry if this isn't obvious enough but first timer here. I spent the weekend on a similar problem which was something pretty damn obvious. It seems to be failing an `if` even if it's obviously supposed to be `true`.

Comment: Show us the rules in English, like "any trip from the CBD to anywhere outside the CBD incurs $15". In order of preference.

Comment: what do u mean by random location

Comment: @paxdiablo has a point, if you spell it out to yourself you'll see the problem. That's why I talk to http://developerduck.com

Comment: nathan, without the English rules, this question is of little use to anyone else. In other words, it will almost certainly be closed and possibly deleted. You need to edit the rules into your question.

Answer (score 1):

you put Airport as pickup which means FIRST condition

`if(!pickup.equals("CBD") && (!dropOff.equals("CBD"))){
           Surcharge = 15.0; }`

is valid. As pickup is not CBD but airport.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ah crap its always just a stupid mistake! sorry for such a big question than =(

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Airport-to-CBD will _not_ incur $15 surcharge since the second subcondition will be false. Airport-to-anywhere-else will be $15.

Answer (score 0):

In plain English, your first if-statement says:

> If the person isn't being picked up from CBD AND they're not being dropped off to CBD, then charge them $15.

As a result, if neither the pickup or drop-off location is CBD (even if one of them is the airport), then the result will be $15.

It may be easier to approach the problem by using positive tests (e.g. "if the drop-off or pickup location **is** CBD") instead of negative tests (e.g. "if the drop-off or pickup location **is not** CBD").

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your rules say in English:

1. Any trip wholly outside the central business district -> $15
2. Otherwise, any trip not leaving the airport and not arriving at the CBD -> $15
3. Otherwise, any trip where start or finish isn't the airport -> $10
4. Otherwise, any trip where start or finish isn't the CBD -> $5
5. Otherwise -> $0.

You need to establish if that's what you wanted, or you need to give *us* the English rules so we can check your logic.

For a start, your specific trip from the airport to a random location (other than the CBD) *will* incur $15 - see rule 1 above.